# Why does this for loop change the value of a variable?

Tags: c

I don't understand why this program prints:

```
mat[2][0] is -1.824069168023063
```

I want it to print:

```
mat [2][0] is 0.055539784445602
```

I know the error is in the 2nd-3rd `for` loop, however I don't see why this is happening.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i = 0, n, s = 0, t = 0, j = 0;

    n=2;
    double x[n+1], y[n+1];  
    double mat[n + n - 1][n];
    y[0]=2.2;
    y[1]=2.3;
    y[2]=2.4;
    x[0]=0.110362266922174;
    x[1]=0.055539784445602;
    x[2]=0.002507683297244; 

    for (i = 0; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        mat[s][0] = x[i];
        mat[s][1] = y[i];
        printf ("mat %d 0 is %.15lf\n", s, mat[s][0]);
        printf ("mat %d 1 is %.15lf\n", s, mat[s][1]);
        s = s + 2;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        t = i;
        for (j = 0; j <= n - i; j++)
        {
            mat[t][i + 1] = (mat[t + 1][i] - mat[t - 1][i]) / (mat[t + i][0] - mat[t - i][0]);
            printf ("mat[%d][%d] is %.15lf\n", t, i + 1, mat[t][i + 1]);
            t = t + 2;
        }
    }

    printf("mat[2][0] is %.15lf",mat[2][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

I know it is not necessary to use `n` here, and I could just use `n=3` without using `n` as an `int` variable, but this is just a part of a larger code, so please ignore that.

Comment: can you explain in words what are you trying to do? In particular, please explan why should mat[2][0] be what you expect it to be

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. What have you done so far to try to troubleshoot this yourself? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to make sure each line of code is doing what you are expecting?  Or added additional print statements to make sure your variables are the values you are expecting at each step?

Comment: looping to `<= n` looks ripe for overflow to me, as does the `i + 1` in `mat[t][i + 1]`

Comment: `mat[t][i + 1]` out of bounds at `i = n` (`2 + 1 = 3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing past the end of your arrays.

You allocate:

```
double mat[n + n - 1][n];
```

Since `n=2`, that means each row has two columns, `[0]` and `[1]`.

So when you write to `mat[1][2]`, that's past the end of `mat[1]`. Which is undefined behavior, so it could do anything from segfaulting to spending your entire savings on a fly-by-night scam cryptocurrency. But, because of the way the arrays are allocated on your system, `mat[2]` ends up right after `mat[1]` in memory, with no gap, so a write to `mat[1][2]` goes into `mat[2][0]`.

Your code can also write to `[3]`, and in fact does so at `mat[2][3]`, because you're looping over `i <= n` and writing to `mat[t][i+1]`.

You haven't explained what any of these values are supposed to mean, and I'm having a very hard time guessing (e.g., what is the `j` loop for, when you never even use `j` in it?), so I can't tell you for sure how to fix your code to do whatever it is you wanted to do.

But I can guess, based on the fact that you called the thing `mat`, that maybe you wanted a square matrix. In which case, the fix is probably as simple as this:

```
double mat[n + n - 1][n + n - 1];
```

But even that isn't correct, because `n + n - 1` is 3, and `mat[2][3]` will still write past the end. So maybe you actually wanted this:

```
double mat[n + n][n + n];
```